# Keep Widget always visible while changing pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently using Navigator.pushNamed for changing the content of my app and I would like to have a persistent widget on top of every page without loading it every time I change a page. Is it possible or I have to change my entire app to use one scaffold and update the content of the scaffold? I would like to avoid this solution.

Comment: as I understand, you want a constant widget at top for each page let's say appbar is common and rest is changed. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Page1(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(), // the common thing.
          body: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();// add button to go to Page2
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

---

Description:

`builder` allows you to pass the different widget and each widget will be wrapped with the common widget, AppBar inside the scaffold here. Thus the scaffold and appbar is common for each page you visit.